# How to find if Postgresql v. 9.1 primary key's value is generated by nexval()?

Tags: postgresql

I need dynamically insert new rows into database, but could not find how to define if column which is primary key, is generated by nextval().

Yes, I know http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalogs.html and information_schema, but could not find there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pg_get_serial_sequence()`. The function returns the name of the sequence associated with a column - if there is one. Otherwise it returns null:

```
select pg_get_serial_sequence('public.your_table_name', 'pk_column_name');
```

Note that the column as to be defined as `serial` or `bigserial` (or the sequence must have been "assigned" to the column manually)

If the column is "only" defined as `pk_column integer default nextval('pk_sequence')` then you need to retrieve the default value of the column and parse it manually:

```
select column_name, column_default
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'your_table_name'
and table_schema = 'public'
```